# What can I run on a Ubuntu Server machine to detect hardware failures?

Tags: ubuntu

My machine is booting. What kind of diagnosis program can I run on my Ubuntu Server to have a clue what is broken?

Thanks very much!

Comment: The type of failure almost always indicates which test you should be running.  Just randomly running tests usually won't be very useful.  Have you considered looking at the diagnostic software provided by your hardware manufacturer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memtest86+ - RAM testing.

cpuburn & lmsensors - CPU testing with heavy load.

smartmontools - hard disk SMART testing and monitoring.

[Hardware diagnostics with open source tools](http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/55366)

Answer (score 0):

If you're really desperate to find out what's broken, I'd throw an all-in-one burn-in tool like [Breakin](http://www.advancedclustering.com/software/breakin.html) or [Stress Linux](http://www.stresslinux.org/) and see what floats up.

However, I wouldn't bother doing that.  Hardware is cheap enough, and your time (and the time of your users) is valuable enough (I hope, anyway) that it's cheaper and quicker just to ship 'em a new box and be done with it.  Have the old one shipped back for testing if you're feeling curious, but don't bother trying to fix the problem while users are getting no work done.